# Detect zoom level in Firefox Mobile

Tags: javascript, firefox, zooming, fennec

I do "pinch" zooming on mobile Firefox 30.0 and want to know actual zoom level. What I try:

- Lib for detection https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom (it uses binary search to detect zoom level on Firefox) but it returns same value for different zoom levels.
- **window.devicePixelRatio** works nice for Desktop Firefox version, but this value also has no changes when change zoom level.

My question: is there any way to detect current zoom level on Firefox mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issu with the github library you mentioned, solved for me modifying the lines:

```
var firefox18 = function () {
    return {zoom: firefox4().zoom, devicePxPerCssPx: devicePixelRatio()};
};
```

into:

```
var firefox18 = function () {
    var zoom = screen.width;
    if (window.orientation == 90) {
        zoom = screen.height;
    }
    zoom = zoom / window.innerWidth;
    return {zoom: zoom, devicePxPerCssPx: devicePixelRatio()};
};
```